# clacks in external sound card on 19.10

Tags: usb, sound, 19.10, soundcard

I have an external sound card, exactly mixer Behringer Xenyx Q1002USB. And it worked perfectly in my previous Ubuntu Studio 19.04 and 18.10 and 18.04...
but now, after update to 19.10 - basically, it works well. But after some time from startup it begins quietly but annoyingly clacking.

It's horrible and fixes only by restart the computer. Resetting or unplug/replug or turn off/turn on of the mixer does not fix this.
But if I unplug mixer from usb the clacks disappear. So this is exactly problem in Ubuntu.
Fresh install did not fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by update kernel from 5.0.x to 5.3.x.